# MS excel formula to extract values from text

Tags: excel

please advice how to sum values by condition.

I have a row of cells with text values: 1x, 2y, 5x, 7y, 9y, 2x, 6x.

How to get the sum of Xs or Ys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try-

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$G$1,C6,""),0))
```

You may need array entry for older version of excel. Array entry means enter formula by `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]